# Change sender on DocuSign envelope within EnvelopesAPI

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I'm sending documents electronically successfully within an app using DocuSign.

Depending on who's logged into the app I was hoping to change the sender email address..so they can get notified of any responses via email.

Is this possible using EnvelopesAPI, I don't have to create an account with each user's email address, do I?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your c# try adding the below code, This overrides the **reply to** in an email.

```
EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();
envDef.EmailSettings = new EmailSettings();
envDef.EmailSettings.ReplyEmailAddressOverride = YOUR_LOGGEDIN_USEREMAIL;
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.